# Json pojo mapping for Dynamic JSON response

Tags: java, json

I have the two jsons file, I want to know how to handle this dynamic JSON response:

1>

```
{ 
 "Detail": {
       "name": "jean",
       "address": "something",
        "id": 4 
 } }
```

2>

```
 { "Detail": {
       "name": "jean",
       "address": something, 
       "id": 4,
       "alternateAddress":"something1"

} }
```

But the java model is as follows:

```
public class Detail {

private String id;
private String name;
private String address;
private String alternateAddress;  //how to handle this?
```

// getter and setters here...

```
}
```

I want both of these json to work irrespective of whether "alternateAddress" property is available or not i.e present in json object or not

I dont want to remove alternateAddress from pojo and want it to get used based on whether its present in json or not

Thanks in advance

Comment: what have you tried so far?, ideally json should do exactly what you are asking for here... do you get any exceptions while deserializing?

Comment: It will just be set to null, if it is not in the JSON, why would that be a problem? I believe null - while a bit controversial at that - is to be used to convey the meaning "value is not present"...

Comment: Thanks Anantha Sharma for your reply.Actually i got confused

Answer (score 0):

What parser are you using?

With the jackson parser you can ignore elements not present in the JSON when deserializing by using the @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) annotation.  That way only fields that are present in the JSON are populated in the POJO and no exceptions are thrown when parsing.